# Google Analytics: if you add dimension "previous page" - does it cull 1st pages from the records?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I have a report of pageviews for each destination page.

I also have a second report that has previous page -> destination page pageviews.

Oddly, the numbers agree on some pages, but wildly disagree on others.

I want to say that --- it's almost like -- the previous page path is nonexistent, or null, for the 1st page someone arrives at ... (not talking about the referral source) --- so instead of returning 'null' for previous page in these queries, these records are simply ignored entirely and purged from the report.

Is that right?

Still, even with that in mind, it does not precisely add up. The biggest landing page (homepage) is almost cut in half, yet other pages --- the numbers are identical, even though meager traffic arrives at them as well.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

If the destination page is the first page, then the previous page path of the destination page will be '(entrance)', not NULL or blank.